# How to implement Refresh Token in Service Account

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, token, gspread

I am a student currently doing a digital sign in page as a project. I'm relatively new to Python but I need help with implementing a refresh token because after the sign in page has been open for an hour, it stops uploading entries to the Google sheet it's supposed to update with a log. Here's the gspread setup:

```
import guizero
import tkinter
import datetime
import gspread
import time

from oauth2client.service_account 
import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' ]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('ESDSignInSheet.json', scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("ESD & Cleanroom Approved Persons & Parts List ").worksheet('ESD APPROVAL LIST')

log = client.open("ESD Sign In Log").sheet1
```

Let me know if any more info is needed for you to help me. Thank you in advance for the help!